# Which kind of Azure diagnositcs log stores the data for webrole instance count change, start, stop, Upgrade etc.?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-diagnostics

Which kind of Azure diagnositcs log stores the data for webrole instance count change, start, strop, Upgrade etc.? I need to store this logs for my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Azure Role instance count data is not stored through Windows Azure Diagnostics log. Windows Azure Diagnostics is designed to store log information inside the instance related to resources, application so you can get such data from it.

However instance specific data such as Start, Stop, Ready etc is already stored in your VM outside Azure Diagnostics scope (mean you have nothing to do in your VM to get this data, it is logged by default). This data is stored directly by Windows Azure VM AppAgent and the size could be in several Megabytes so you sure can RDP to Azure VM and take a look at this log data. I will not suggest you to move this log data from Azure VM as it may not be any use for you.

To see such log you just need to RDP to your Azure VM and visit **C:\logs** folder and the log will be in file name i.e. WaAppAgent.###.log and opening these log files you can see the current instance status:

```
[00000011] [06/07/2012 12:01:03.01] WaAppAgent Heartbeat.
[00000011] [06/07/2012 12:01:03.01] Role ***.MainWebRole_IN_0 is reporting state Ready.
[00000012] [06/07/2012 12:01:04.32] Role ***.MainWebRole_IN_0 has current state Started, desired state Started, and goal state execution status StartSucceeded.
[00000011] [06/07/2012 12:01:08.01] WaAppAgent Heartbeat.
```

As long as your role is running such file are accumulating in several counts so while it is good to have this info however I just don't see that you are going to get any big value for it. 
I have written a tool to summarize these logs to tell when the last time role was started or stopped so you can try here: http://azurevmassist.codeplex.com/

Comment: Awesome tool Avkash, how am I only hearing about it now, kudos!!